# Taking multiline inputs in java command line

Tags: java, stdin

The problem I'm trying to solve is given an integer N find the digits in this number that exactly divide N(division that leaves 0 as remainder) and display their count. For N=24, there are 2 digits − 2 & 4. Both of these digits exactly divide 24. So our answer is 2. The input format is The first line contains T (number of test cases) followed by T lines (each containing an integer N).
Here's my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            System.out.println("Please enter your inputs");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String line;

           ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

        int i=0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && line.length() != 0){
            arr.add(line);
            i++;
        }

            if(Integer.parseInt(args[0]) != (args.length -1)){
                System.out.println("Wrong number of inputs");
            }else{
                for(int j = 1; j< args.length; j++){

                    System.out.println(findDivisor(Integer.parseInt(args[j])));

                }
            }


        }
        public static int findDivisor(int n){
            int count = 0;
            String s = Integer.toString(n);
            char[] c= s.toCharArray();
            for(int i = 0; i< c.length; i++){
                String temp = Character.toString(c[i]);
                int num = Integer.parseInt(s);
                if(num == 0)
                    count += 0;
                else if(n%num == 0){
                    count +=1;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
```

On adding an Arraylist to read to inputs, the program goes into an infinite loop it seems. As in based on the first input I need to take the number of inputs and then process. As in if the first input is 2, my program should await 2 more command line inputs and on the third press of enter run. How do I invoke that functionality into this code.

Comment: Java arrays aren't dynamically sized. Use a `Collection` like `ArrayList`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Please see edits.

Comment: Now change the next statements to work with `arr` and not `args`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Read in T.
        int T = sc.nextInt();

        // Read in T integers, for each print the number of digit divisors.
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++){
            int n = sc.nextInt()
            System.out.println(findDivisor(n));
        }
}
```

If you want to wait until all input is in first, create an array of size T to keep track of your integers:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Read in T.
        int T = sc.nextInt();

        int[] myNumbers = new int[T];

        // Read in all input, and calculate the number of digit divisors.
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++){
            int n = sc.nextInt()
            myNumbers[i] = findDivisor(n);
        }

        // For each input, print out the number of digit divisors.
        System.out.println("Number of digit divisors:");
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++){
            System.out.println(myNumbers[i]);
        }
}
```